# Remove last Github commit, without removing code in local repository

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, atlassian-sourcetree

In my unity3d game project, I'm using Atlassian SourceTree for committing code to my Github repository.
The last commit has wrong commit message, and I wanted to change commit message(as I googled, that's impossible).
So the last chance for me is to revert the last commit and make a new one with the correct commit message.
How could this be done using Atlassian SourceTree utility.

Comment: Wow, rare to see developer who cares about commit messages. Respect.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski, yep. I was pretty drunk on the weekend, and forgot that I made the commit message in Russian(other commits were in English).

Answer (score 2):

Impossible? I think not!

Just open up a cmd, go to your project and write `git commit --amend -m "your new message"` and then `git push --force`. This will edit the last comment's commit message and then force push the branch to force your edit on history. (force push is necessary since you're manipulating history and will overwrite/force the remote branch to look like your local branch. Use with care if you're in a project with more people)

Comment: Just tested and it works. Good to know about it. Thanks. BTW, how to change message for other than last commit?

Comment: You described a solution using git command prompt. I'm using SourceTree(without the git command prompt).
Just was looking for another solution.

Comment: Oh, okay - but you _can_ still use this solution. SourceTree is just a layer that uses the git commands when you click on buttons. You can still open up any CMD or whatever and write these things. I am sorry, I don't know how to solve it in SourceTree.

Comment: @Fredrik, >Use with care if you're in a project with more people
I'm autistic and always work alone.

Comment: Hehe ok! A lone wolf needn't fear the force push as much, but either way, it's important to know what it does and to use with care. You need to know that `git push --force` will FORCE the remote branch (usually "origin") to look like your local branch. Meaning, if there is something you've pushed before and then you check out an earlier commit and force push your branch from there, all the things that you don't have locally, but is on the remote, will disappear.

Comment: Just DON'T do `git push --force` if you don't know git.

Answer (score 1):

If you already pushed to the remote, I'd advise to forget about it. It's dangerous to re-write git history that was pushed if you don't know git very well.

If you didn't push and you didn't create any other commits on the top of it, you can do as the other answer says and *amend* a new commit with your last commit.

To do it in SourceTree, unstage all changes that you may have and press the commit button (like if you were creating an empty commit). Then, in the message tab click in *Commit Options* and select *Amend last commit*. You should see your former message now, change it and commit.

Again, don't do it if you pushed this commit to the remote, don't use `push --force`.

[image: push]